# Create or open file in python

Tags: python, file-io

In python, I want to open a file if already exists or create it if it doesnt exist. also i want to write to the file new contents on opening it without overwriting the existing contents of the file. How can I do it?

Comment: is there anything you have done so far?

Comment: yes, I used like f=open(file1,'w+') that creates a file and i am nt able to make out whether it is opening the file if exists because the read()operation is ain't working since i opened in 'W' mode. and now if i write anything its overwriting the contents

Comment: `file_object = open('my_file.txt', mode='a+')`

Comment: wowww. Thanks Trimax, its working!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python)

Comment: my question was how to create a file if doesnt exists and open the same file if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP8 suggests you to use:

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.write( "Your new content" )
```

The `with` statement is better because it will ensure you always close the file, even if an exception is raised.

Example adapted from: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#pep-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
file = open('myfile.dat', 'a+')
```

Refer to this link for details: 
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html